# draggable="false" not working while user-select: none is defined in the CSS

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, draggable

I have a text link which I'm using as a logo for a site, and I don't want the link to be draggable or selectable (purely for aesthetics, it's only going to be a local site). I was going to ask why `draggable="false"` wasn't working, but then I discovered that if I removed `user-select: none;` from the CSS, it worked fine. Here is my code (note: the text is meant to be black with no `text-decoration`, but there's no need to define that because I'm using a reset stylesheet as well):

```css
.logo {
    padding: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    user-select: none;
}

.heading {
    font-family: 'Yeseva One', serif;
    font-size: 3em;
}

.heading a {
    transition: 200ms;
}

.heading a:hover {
    color: #c1250f;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
    <h1 class="heading"><a href="#" draggable="false">Title</a></h1>
</div>
```

Do you have any idea why they don't work in conjunction? And is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. When ```draggable="false"``` and ```user-select: none;``` are present in your code, they both seem to function fine.

Comment: @ZachP. They should function fine, but they don't. At least not for me.

Comment: Are you able to upload a video of your interaction with it?

Comment: @ZachP. Sure, give me a minute.

Comment: Which browser are you testing in?

Comment: @ZachP. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/8cBQMNF). For some reason OBS didn't capture the dragged image, but you can kind of tell what's going on.

Comment: @NathanielFlick I'm using Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect but cursor: none on that link means it gets no cursor on hover and dragging is limited. You're fighting browser defaults here but this pretty much does what you want.

```css
.logo {
    padding: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    user-select: none;
}

.heading {
    font-family: 'Yeseva One', serif;
    font-size: 3em;
}

.heading a {
    transition: 200ms;
}

.heading a:hover {
    color: #c1250f;
}

.no-drag {
cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
    <h1 class="heading"><a class="no-drag" href="#" draggable="false">Title</a></h1>
</div>
```